# Is there a way to select rows by replacing duplicate values to null

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select a table without duplicates

Selecting this table.

```
Tag   Description     Type
A     Car             Sports
A     Car             Hatchback
B     Truck           Mixer
B     Truck           Fire
```

and then and change duplicate values to null if it is the same as above,
that makes the table like this.

```
Tag   Description     Type
A     Car             Sports
                      Hatchback
B     Truck           Mixer
                      Fire
```

Tried distinct but it displays like the in the first table.

Comment: Seems like a `GROUP BY` to me.

Comment: You should probably handle this in your presentation layer, e.g. PHP.  If you want to handle this from MySQL, then you should tell us what is the logic for which type has its description shown and which does not.

Comment: these data are by default and i just have to filtered it out. Sorry if my answer is far from your question. im still trying to learn english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to display the description only for the alphabetically greatest type of each tag, and you are using MySQL 8+, then we can try using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tag ORDER BY Type DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Tag END AS Tag,
    CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Description END AS Description,
    Type
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Tag IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    Tag,
    rn;
```

Comment: Thank you for the great help! I just have to fix the query now as null tags always get on top of it. btw much appreciated!

Comment: @Jet Just add another level to the `ORDER BY` clause to place all `NULL` tags last, see my updated answer above.

Comment: i dont know if mysql is messing but with your updated answer the table still show nulls at the top but `GROUP BY` fixed it. Thank you very much.